# TagSetDelay the Plus[ ] function for direcy use with Datasets

Tags: programming, dataset, recursion

I am trying to define a **particular behavior of the function Plus[]** when the arguments are $n$ Dataset, with $n\geq 3$.

(The goal is to mimic the behavior of Plus[] with Datasets instead of numbers)

Typically, if $d_1, \ldots, d_n$ are datasets, I want that $d_1+\cdots+d_n$ returns a "simplified sum" of the datasets as $d_{i_1} +\cdots +d_{i_p}$ in the following sense :

My datasets $d_i$ have the form :

`Dataset[{<|"price"->p,"item"->i|>}]`

I start by grouping the datasets with same item:

`Values[GroupBy[{datasetSequence},#["item"]&]`

and then I add the prices of datasets with identical item :

`Map[sumOfValues,Values[GroupBy[{datasetSequence},#["item"]&]`

here, the `sumOfValues` function is defined by :

`sumOfValues[d1_Dataset,d2_Dataset]:=Dataset[{<|"price"->d1["price"]+d2["price"],"item"->d1["item"|>}]`

and

`sumOfValues[a_,b_,c__]:=sumOfValues[sumOfValues[a,b],c]`

The problem comes when I try to TagSetDelayed the Plus[] function as follows :

`Unprotect[Plus]`

`Plus/: Plus[Repeated[datasetSequence__Dataset,{3,300}]]:=Total[Map[sumOfValues@@#&,Values[GroupBy[{datasetSequence},#["item"]&]]`

It seems that there is a recursive problem but I do not know how to overcome it.

I already tested to add a stopping criterion as follows :

`stop[listOfDatasets_List]:=Module[{itemList},itemList=Sort[Map[#["item"]&,listOfDatasets]]; Not[Sort[DeleteDuplicates[itemList]]==itemList]]`

and

`Plus/: Plus[Repeated[datasetSequence__Dataset,{3,300}]]:=Total[Map[sumOfValues@@#&,Values[GroupBy[{datasetSequence},#["item"]&]]/;stop[{datasetSequence}]`

Thank you beforehand for your help

Comment: You could try the Villegas-Gayley trick `Plus[ ...] /; ! TrueQ[$inside] := Block[{$inside = True}, code]`. I'm wary of overloading system functions, especially ones like `Plus` that have special rules. The special rules mean I cannot be certain I know what I'm doing. An alternative I've used is my own private head: `myDS[Dataset[...]]` and overload `Plus` for `myDS`: `myDS /: Plus[myDS[d1_],...` etc. Another option would be to define `myPlus` for adding datasets, but I suspect that won't fit your design as well. I'll let others suggest ways to leverage `Dataset` functionality (I can't).

Comment: Well, maybe I can: `Plus // Unprotect;
Plus[datasetSequence__Dataset] := GroupBy[
  Join[datasetSequence],
  Key@"item" -> Key@"price",   Total  ] // KeyValueMap[Function[{key, value}, <|"price" -> value, "item" -> key|>]];
Plus // Protect;` -- It would only work on datasets of this exact form and mess up if other datasets are (accidentally) added.

Comment: Is your goal truly "to mimic the behavior of Plus[] with Datasets instead of numbers", or is your goal to analyze/manipulate your data? Building a special algebra over specially structured Datasets seems unnecessarily complicated and insufficiently general to be useful. If you really want an algebra, I'd suggest you define it over Association rather than Dataset (you're datasets are so thin that they're not adding anything. On the other hand if you just did Join@@datasetSequence, you'd have a meaningful Dataset that you could run your queries/aggregations against in the normal fashion.